# Does ActiveRecord perform inserts/deletes in bulk when inside a transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, transactions

What I need:

1. ensuring atomic updates (no record can gets processed 2 times)
2. bulk deletion for all 1000 rows selected

---

```
@queue = Queue.where("col = 1").limit(1000)
ids = []
@queue.each do |row|
    Queue.do_something(row)
    ids << row.id
end

Queue.delete_all("id in (#{ids.join(',')}) ")
```

IS THE SAME AS

```
Queue.transaction do
    @queue.each do |row|
        Queue.do_something(row)
        Queue.delete(row.id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For inserts:

ActiveRecord does not perform a bulk insert when using a transaction. However it does speed things up a bit since it is using a single transaction to execute all INSERT statements as opposed to one transaction per INSERT statement otherwise.

So:

```
Queue.transaction do 
  @queue.each do |row|
    # an INSERT is done here
  end
end
```

is going to be faster than:

```
@queue.each do |row|
  # an INSERT is done here
end
```

For more info on how to really do bulk inserts, check out this [article](http://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/).

For deletes:

The ActiveRecord `delete_all` call is one single SQL DELETE statement, so I guess you could consider this as a bulk delete (no need to use a transaction here since it's already encapsulated in one transaction by ActiveRecord). This is not the case when calling `delete` on each record, which will result in multiple SQL DELETE statements, thus multiple transactions initiated and committed and overall slower performance.

Comment: In my case I need to DELETE records while ensuring no other processes/instances will process the same RECORD. I using mysql "FOR UPDATE" SQL clause to lock the selected records and using ActiveRecord transaction because I thought ActiveRecord would performe those deletions as a single mass delete sql or do it faster.

Comment: The problem is that I had the same email ( record on QUEUE) delivered 2 times

Comment: It really gets a lot faster when using your solution... Thanks! :-)

Comment: If you want the next level speed bump, check out ActiveRecord Import.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at ActiveRecord Import: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import.

I'm using this tool to insert between 10,000 and 100,000 rows of data.

```
books = []
10.times do |i| 
  books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}")
end
Book.import books
```

If you're using MySQL, it also supports ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE so you can intelligently insert new / update old rows. https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/MySQL:-On-Duplicate-Key-Update-Support